# Android - Moving to the main thread after a JsonObjectRequest

Tags: android, multithreading

I'm fairly new to Android (exclusively in Java) and I'm afraid I might not have learned a few things properly.

Currently I have a fragment which shows a recyclerview. The data is loaded from a remote Json file.

This is what I have in the fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_library, container, false);

    libraryList = new LibraryHandler().getLibrary(new ShowListAsyncResponse() {
        @Override
        public void processFinished(ArrayList<Object> showArrayList) {
            recyclerViewAdapter = new LibraryRecyclerViewAdapter(getContext(), libraryList);

            libraryRecyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.libraryRecyclerView);
            libraryRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            libraryRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
            libraryRecyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
        }
    });

    return v;
}
```

LibraryHandler is the class that loads the data from the server:

```
public class LibraryHandler {
private final String url = "https://path/to/api";

private ArrayList<Object> libraryList = new ArrayList<>();

public ArrayList<Object> getLibrary(final ShowListAsyncResponse callBack) {

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            url,
            null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    try {
                        JSONArray showsJsonArray = response.getJSONArray("shows");
                        JSONArray moviesJsonArray = response.getJSONArray("movies");

                        // Shows
                        for (int i = 0; i< showsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject showObject = showsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            Gson gson = new Gson();
                            Show show = gson.fromJson(String.valueOf(showObject), Show.class);

                            libraryList.add(show);
                        }

                        // Movies
                        for (int i = 0; i< moviesJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject movieObject = moviesJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            Gson gson = new Gson();
                            Movie movie = gson.fromJson(String.valueOf(movieObject), Movie.class);

                            libraryList.add(movie);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    if (null != callBack) callBack.processFinished(libraryList);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }

    );

    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);

    return libraryList;
}
```

The interface is simply

```
public interface ShowListAsyncResponse {
    void processFinished(ArrayList<Object> showArrayList);
}
```

I've read that the adapter code should be called from the Main Thread. Am I in the main thread within the processFinished function? And if not, how can I modify in order to run those lines from the main thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentation:

> Volley always delivers parsed responses on the main thread. Running on the main thread is convenient for populating UI controls with received data, as you can freely modify UI controls directly from your response handler

So `onResponse()` callback is triggered in the Main thread, and so as `callBack.processFinished()` call.

So, you can safely build-up the `RecyclerView` when the `processFinished()` is triggered.

You could have a look at [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/) for more info.

Also make sure not to have a heavy work on this callback as it runs on main thread.